# Disable days by array of numbers jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This is the code that i have been working upon:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (day) {
        for (var q = 0; q < final_array.length; q++) {

            if (final_array[q] == 1 || final_array[q] == 2 || final_array[q] == 3 || final_array[q] == 4 || final_array[q] == 5 || final_array[q] == 6) {
                return [false, ''];
            } else {
                return [true, ''];
            }
        }
    }
});
```

my final_array looks like this "[2, 3, 4, 5]" i want to disable Tuesdays, Wednesdays, Fridays and  Saturdays. When I run this code i am not getting any output. Not even errors also. can anyone help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try filtering days using `$.inArray()`

```
var final_array = [2,3,5,6];
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [$.inArray(day, final_array) == -1]
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9Fy9/999/)**

Also, `[2,3,4,5]` would mean Tuesdays, Wednesdays, Thursdays and Fridays and not *i want to disable Tuesdays, Wednesdays, Fridays and Saturdays* as you said. Use `[2,3,5,6]` instead.

Comment: Can you print `final_array` in your console and post the result here?

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue in a **[FIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)** ? Also the version of datepicker you are using and What is not working in your code?

Comment: Unfortunately i can't I'm using ajax(communicating with database) to gain dates and store them in final_array.

Comment: You can, by putting static array as Input temporarily.

Comment: Check now http://jsfiddle.net/6d169gL9/2/. Its working. Add `$('#datepicker').datepicker("show");` in the end.

Comment: it still does nothing.

Comment: Did you check the update fiddle? You had not included jQuery reference and jQuery UI reference. Please include them in `<head>` section. Also there were console errors for extra parantheses.

Comment: yea I checked updated fiddle and  fixed parantheses bug. my header looks like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/5tsekpj1/